# Icon displaying after hovering

Tags: css

I can't see the icon until i hover over it.

This is for a shopify website

I'm using this code to call

```
"<div class="icon-button twitter">
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i><span></span>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com" </a>
                  </div>"
```

This is the main code that I'm using.
So, everything works, but instead of the icon displaying on my website before i hover over it, there is nothing there. It's blank. When i move my mouse over it it does it effect.

```
html {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Wrapper */
.icon-button {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2.6rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    height: 2.6rem;
    line-height: 2.6rem;
    margin: 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    width: 2.6rem;
}

/* Circle */
.icon-button span {
    border-radius: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
       -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
         -o-transition: all 0.3s;
            transition: all 0.3s;
    width: 0;
}
.icon-button:hover span {
    width: 2.6rem;
    height: 2.6rem;
    border-radius: 2.6rem;
    margin: -1.3rem;
}

/* Icons */
.icon-button i {
    background: none;
    color: white;
    height: 2.6rem;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 2.6rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
       -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
         -o-transition: all 0.3s;
            transition: all 0.3s;
    width: 2.6rem;
    z-index: 10;
}





.twitter span {
    background-color: #4099ff;
}
.facebook span {
    background-color: #3B5998;
}
.google-plus span {
    background-color: #db5a3c;
}
.tumblr span {
    background-color: #34526f;
}
.instagram span {
    background-color: #517fa4;
}
.youtube span {
    background-color: #bb0000;
}
.pinterest span {
    background-color: #cb2027;
}



.icon-button .icon-twitter {
    color: #4099ff;
}
.icon-button .icon-facebook {
    color: #3B5998;
}
.icon-button .fa-tumblr {
    color: #34526f;
}
.icon-button .icon-google-plus {
    color: #db5a3c;
}
.icon-button .fa-instagram {

  color: #FD1D1D;

}
.icon-button .fa-youtube {
    color: #bb0000;
}
.icon-button .fa-pinterest {
    color: #cb2027;
}




.icon-button:hover .icon-twitter,
.icon-button:hover .icon-facebook,
.icon-button:hover .icon-google-plus,
.icon-button:hover .fa-tumblr,
.icon-button:hover .fa-instagram,
.icon-button:hover .fa-youtube,
.icon-button:hover .fa-pinterest {
    color: white;
}

@media all and (max-width: 680px) {
  .icon-button {
    border-radius: 1.6rem;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    height: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    width: 1.6rem;
  }

  .icon-button:hover span {
    width: 1.6rem;
    height: 1.6rem;
    border-radius: 1.6rem;
    margin: -0.8rem;
  }

  /* Icons */
  .icon-button i {
      height: 1.6rem;
      line-height: 1.6rem;
      width: 1.6rem;
  }
  body {

      padding: 10px;
  }
  .pinterest {
   display: none; 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be because icon colors are the same as button backgrounds:

```css
.icon-button {
  background-color: white;
  ...
}

.icon-button i {
  color: white;
  ...
}
```

I've changed the background color of buttons to gray as a demonstration:

```css
html {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Wrapper */

.icon-button {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 2.6rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  height: 2.6rem;
  line-height: 2.6rem;
  margin: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 2.6rem;
}


/* Circle */

.icon-button span {
  border-radius: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 0;
}

.icon-button:hover span {
  width: 2.6rem;
  height: 2.6rem;
  border-radius: 2.6rem;
  margin: -1.3rem;
}


/* Icons */

.icon-button i {
  background: none;
  color: white;
  height: 2.6rem;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 2.6rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 2.6rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

.twitter span {
  background-color: #4099ff;
}

.facebook span {
  background-color: #3B5998;
}

.google-plus span {
  background-color: #db5a3c;
}

.tumblr span {
  background-color: #34526f;
}

.instagram span {
  background-color: #517fa4;
}

.youtube span {
  background-color: #bb0000;
}

.pinterest span {
  background-color: #cb2027;
}

.icon-button .icon-twitter {
  color: #4099ff;
}

.icon-button .icon-facebook {
  color: #3B5998;
}

.icon-button .fa-tumblr {
  color: #34526f;
}

.icon-button .icon-google-plus {
  color: #db5a3c;
}

.icon-button .fa-instagram {
  color: #FD1D1D;
}

.icon-button .fa-youtube {
  color: #bb0000;
}

.icon-button .fa-pinterest {
  color: #cb2027;
}

.icon-button:hover .icon-twitter,
.icon-button:hover .icon-facebook,
.icon-button:hover .icon-google-plus,
.icon-button:hover .fa-tumblr,
.icon-button:hover .fa-instagram,
.icon-button:hover .fa-youtube,
.icon-button:hover .fa-pinterest {
  color: white;
}

@media all and (max-width: 680px) {
  body {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .icon-button {
    border-radius: 1.6rem;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    height: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    width: 1.6rem;
  }
  .icon-button:hover span {
    width: 1.6rem;
    height: 1.6rem;
    border-radius: 1.6rem;
    margin: -0.8rem;
  }
  /* Icons */
  .icon-button i {
    height: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    width: 1.6rem;
  }
  .pinterest {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="icon-button twitter">
  <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i><span></span>
  <a href="https://twitter.com"></a>
</div>
```

---

### Edit

Upon further investigation, I notice that there is no CSS definition for `.fa-twitter` in your code. I've changed the element's class to "icon-twitter".

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
  html {
    font-size: 2.5em;
  }
  
  body {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  /* Wrapper */
  
  .icon-button {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2.6rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    height: 2.6rem;
    line-height: 2.6rem;
    margin: 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    width: 2.6rem;
  }
  /* Circle */
  
  .icon-button span {
    border-radius: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    width: 0;
  }
  
  .icon-button:hover span {
    width: 2.6rem;
    height: 2.6rem;
    border-radius: 2.6rem;
    margin: -1.3rem;
  }
  /* Icons */
  
  .icon-button i {
    background: none;
    color: white;
    height: 2.6rem;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 2.6rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    width: 2.6rem;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  
  .twitter span {
    background-color: #4099ff;
  }
  
  .facebook span {
    background-color: #3B5998;
  }
  
  .google-plus span {
    background-color: #db5a3c;
  }
  
  .tumblr span {
    background-color: #34526f;
  }
  
  .instagram span {
    background-color: #517fa4;
  }
  
  .youtube span {
    background-color: #bb0000;
  }
  
  .pinterest span {
    background-color: #cb2027;
  }
  
  .icon-button .icon-twitter {
    color: #4099ff;
  }
  
  .icon-button .icon-facebook {
    color: #3B5998;
  }
  
  .icon-button .fa-tumblr {
    color: #34526f;
  }
  
  .icon-button .icon-google-plus {
    color: #db5a3c;
  }
  
  .icon-button .fa-instagram {
    color: #FD1D1D;
  }
  
  .icon-button .fa-youtube {
    color: #bb0000;
  }
  
  .icon-button .fa-pinterest {
    color: #cb2027;
  }
  
  .icon-button:hover .icon-twitter,
  .icon-button:hover .icon-facebook,
  .icon-button:hover .icon-google-plus,
  .icon-button:hover .fa-tumblr,
  .icon-button:hover .fa-instagram,
  .icon-button:hover .fa-youtube,
  .icon-button:hover .fa-pinterest {
    color: white;
  }
  
  @media all and (max-width: 680px) {
    .icon-button {
      border-radius: 1.6rem;
      font-size: 0.8rem;
      height: 1.6rem;
      line-height: 1.6rem;
      width: 1.6rem;
    }
    .icon-button:hover span {
      width: 1.6rem;
      height: 1.6rem;
      border-radius: 1.6rem;
      margin: -0.8rem;
    }
    /* Icons */
    .icon-button i {
      height: 1.6rem;
      line-height: 1.6rem;
      width: 1.6rem;
    }
    body {
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .pinterest {
      display: none;
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="icon-button twitter">
  <i class="fab icon-twitter"></i><span></span>
  <a href="https://twitter.com"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I took the code from here and the background is white and the icon still shows. https://codepen.io/hablufat/pen/eaLdNg?editors=1111 . I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong because when i hover over it the icon appears as it's suppose to, but it's not there "static"

Comment: There is no CSS definition in your code for `.fa-twitter`, only for `.icon-twitter`.

Comment: I replaced the .icon-twitter to fab fa-twitter and now the icon is there and constant, but when i hover over it, it's all a big blue circle.

Comment: also your a element isnt properly formed, `<a href="https://twitter.com" </a>` should be `<a href="https://twitter.com"></a>`

Comment: I get a T with the code you provided, and if i put <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i><span></span> I don't see the icon until I hover over it. I'm now confused even more.

Comment: Perhaps you are including different FontAwesome stylesheets than I am. I included the two stylesheets from the CodePen you referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Just for others I changed .icon-twitter to .fa-twitter and   .icon-button .icon-twitter to .icon-button .fa-twitter. Thank you , i could not have done it without your help - This is my first ever try at CSS lol.

Thank you all again.